# PHP Post param converting to zero when casted to int o intval used

Tags: php

Please see this code in PHP

```
 $ind_ginger = intval($_POST['ind_ginger']) ;
```

`$ind_ginger` is always coming up as `0` when input things like "2" or '2' .

I tried to cast using `(int)` also. 
I want this post param converting to int always. From HTML page they might enter either "2" or '2' or just 2 with out any quotes.

It works fine when the input value does not have quotes around the number like just 1 or 2. Please help.

Comment: $ind_ginger = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ind_ginger', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);   this worked for me

Comment: One suggestion is that if you're taking the number from the user in a text field, give input type='number' so it will take only numerals.